# What is the Z transform of the Discreate PI control model？

Tags: control-theory, pid-control, matlab, simulink

I have a discreate PI controller implemented in stm32 MCU, it has the following form:
$$
 PI=K_p\cdot[r(t_i)-y(t_i)] + (K_I)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{i}[r(t_n)-y(t_n)]\cdot\Delta t
$$
where

- $r(t_i)$ is the target (or input) value,
- $y(t_i)$ is the output value and
- $\Delta t $ is the sampling time.

I use the $\sum$ function to implement the integral function while  the error term is $[r(t_i)-y(t_i)]$.

I need to simulate this PI controller in MATHLAB Simulink.

Besides, I have found another form of the PI controller: it doesn't has the sum equation, and but has the following structure:
$$
PI=K_p\cdot[r(t_i)-y(t_i)]+ (K_I)[r(t_i)-y(t_i)]\cdot\Delta t
$$
For the integral term of this PI controller, the $Z$-transform is
$$
K_I(z)=e(z)\cdot T\cdot\frac{ z}{z-1}.
$$

This form does not include the sum term.

**My question is**: if I use the `sum equation` to sum the error term,  how should I represent the PI controller correctly in the $Z$-transform domain?

Comment: I hope you are not planning to sum the entire history for each computation cycle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is already in discrete form but you need to introduce the $z$-operator to your equation. I perceive a missconception about the z-Transform. I hope the following lines will clarify that...
consider the following

- $e(t) := r(t)-y(t)$

The PI-controller can be represented as

| Continous Time | Frequency Domain |
| --- | --- |
| $$u(t)=K_p\,e(t)+K_I\int_0^{\tau}e(\tau)d\tau$$ | $$U(s)=(K_p+\frac{K_I}{s})\,E(s)$$ |

As probably you notice the proportional part is not a challenge if with want to discretize it, but the integral is! This term could be approached through Euler's forward or backwards method. Using the fordward Euler method leads to

$$u(k\,T) =\int_0^{k\,T}e(\tau)d\tau \approx \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}e(i\,T)\cdot T$$

where T is the sample period, i.e. the loop time in your microcontroller and the notation $u(k\,T)$ denote the value of the variable $u$ at time $k\,T$ with $k=0,1,2...$.

In the Z-Transform domain the operator $z$ is used to denote a forward shift by one sampling interval, e.g. $z\cdot\,x(k)$ is equal to $x(k+1)$. Analogously, the backward shift operator is denoted by $z^{-1}$, e.g. $z^{-1}\cdot x(k) = x(k-1)$.

In digital control systems one can approximate the $s$-Domain in $z$-Transform domain, e.g. using a euler backward integration we have

| Integation in Discrete Time | Integration in Z-Domain |
| --- | --- |
| $$x(k+1)\approx x(k) + T\cdot u(k+1)$$ | $$zX(z)=X(z)+T\,z\,U(z)\,\text{, reordering}\\ \frac{X(z)}{U(z)}=\frac{T\,z}{z-1}$$ |

Which if you noticed, is what you found in the "another" PI-Controller.
Now how the approximation is made? easy, we can recall the integration as $\dot{x}(t)=u(t)$ which in laplace is $\frac{X(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{1}{s}$. Then,

$$\frac{1}{s}\approx\frac{T\,z}{z-1}\,\text{, which leads to}\, s\approx \frac{z-1}{T\,z}$$

The advantage of the last equation is that we can have our Transfer function in Freq Domain and then replace the approximation of $s$, i.e. $C(z)\approx C(s)|_{s=\frac{z-1}{T\,z}}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, you explained it very well.